# hdfs dfs -put : Exception in createBlockOutputStream and java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

[image]

And I checked the webUI which show the datanodes in the unhealthy status. I do not know why this happen.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your configuration or any abnormal termination of datanode(While doing any action on that node)
There is no internal problem with `hdfs dfs -put` , just verify whats inside your directory or use command

```
hdfs dfs -ls /
```

Please specify your problem an error cant be a problem statement until you dont know what you are trying to do.

Comment: when I check my web UI it show that 'LastNodeHealthTime Sat Aug 19 18:05:14 PDT 2017
NodeHealthReport 1/1 local-dirs are bad: /home/centos/hadoop/full/nm-local-dir; 1/1 log-dirs are bad: /soft/hadoop-2.7.3/logs/userlogs' 
Then I check the nm-local-dir file which has 3 files but all empty. I do not know how to find where the problem is . why :(

Comment: Whats your dfs block size

Comment: 128M as default I think. And in logs I also do not know what happened:(

Comment: can you format your namenode :{Note: it will completely erase your data}

Answer (score 0):

File permission issue.

Check file permissions of dfs directory:

```
find /path/to/dfs -group root
```

In general, the user permission group is `hdfs`.
Since I started HDFS service with root user, some dfs block file with `root` permissions was generated.

I solved the problem after change to right permissions:

```
sudo chown -R hdfs:hdfs /path/to/dfs
```